# Share Styling Between CSS Classes

Tags: asp.net, css

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226206/alternating-item-style), I was given a really cool answer to alternating an image and its description between left and right, respectively.  Now I want to apply styling to both, e.g. padding-top, padding-bottom etc. How do I apply a style to both the RowStyle and AlternatingRowStyle in this scenario.

```
<AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="ProductAltItemStyle" />   
<RowStyle CssClass="ProductItemStyle" />
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div class="Image"><asp:Image runat="server" ID="productImage" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("imageUrl") %>' /></div>
            <div class="Description"><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblProductDesc" Width="100%" Text='<%# Eval("productDesc") %>'></asp:Label></div>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I apply styles to multiple classes at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099252/how-can-i-apply-styles-to-multiple-classes-at-once)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively you can do this:

```
<AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="ProductAltItemStyle ProductCommonStyle" />   
<RowStyle CssClass="ProductItemStyle ProductCommonStyle" />
```

ProductCommonStyle contains formatting that is common to both alternating and standard rows.

Even better, you can assign a style to your whole gridview, and use that to define the shared classes:

```
table.GridViewStyle tr td
{
   padding:3px 5px;
   border:1px solid gray;
}

tr.ProductAltItemStyle td
{
    background:white;
}

tr.ProductItemSTyle td
{
    background:silver;
}
```

Comment: I think this is probably the actual answer to this specific question, not that changelog is wrong, but I'm a big believer in CSS following an OO model.

Answer (score 22):

Here's how you do it:

```
.ProductAltItemStyle, .ProductItemStyle {
    // CSS Rules that apply to both go here
}
```

Comment: Small addition, as commented on another CSS question, personally I think having a line-break between each selector (and before the "{" ) is a more obvious readable, searchable format. CSS block formatting is unlike C/C#/Java/JavaScript in this respect.