# How can I apply styles to multiple classes at once?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want two classes with different names to have the same property in CSS. I don't want to repeat the code.

```css
.abc {
   margin-left:20px;
}  
.xyz {
   margin-left:20px;
}
```

```html
<a class="abc">Lorem</a>
<a class="xyz">Ipsum</a>
```

Since both classes are doing the same thing, I should be able to merge it into one. How can I do that?

Answer (score 964, accepted):

```
.abc, .xyz { margin-left: 20px; }
```

is what you are looking for.

Comment: +1, exactly what I was looking for. You can also then have a second, separate entry for .abc and/or .xyz for properties you don't want to apply to both e.g. .xyz {font-weight: bold;} will combine to make .xyz bold and margin-left'ed by 20px but .abc only margin-left'ed.

Answer (score 102):

You can have multiple CSS declarations for the same properties by separating them with commas:

```
.abc, .xyz {
   margin-left: 20px;
}
```

Comment: although the selected answer is completely correct we can not guarantee that newbies will understand what it is doing. I would go with the one explained more. Since it is more of "how to fish" instead of "here is the fish".

Answer (score 27):

Don’t Repeat Your CSS

```
 a.abc, a.xyz{
    margin-left:20px;
 }
```

OR

```
 a{
    margin-left:20px;
 }
```

Comment: I think `abc` was meant as one class name.. and `xyz` as another. Your suggestion is to use use a common class name for common properties which is unnecessary and confusing, given the question.

Answer (score 22):

just seperate the class name with a comma.

```
.a,.b{
your styles
}
```

Answer (score 18):

If you use as following, your code can be more effective than you wrote.
You should add another feature.

```
.abc, .xyz {
margin-left:20px;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
}
```

OR

```
a.abc, a.xyz {
margin-left:20px;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
}
```

OR

```
a {
margin-left:20px;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

And if you have set these classes with their parents before, you should set them with parents (repeat each time) again as below:

```
parent .abc, parent .xyz
```

Comment: Thanks :) This is something I should have known, but....

Answer (score 9):

Using CSS pseudo-classes **[:is](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:is)** (previously **:any** and **:matches**) and **[:where](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:where)**, you can use comma to match multiple classes on any level.

At the root level, `:is(.abc, .xyz)` and `.abc, .xyz` function almost identically. However, **:is** allows matching only a part of the selector without copying the whole selector multiple times.

For example, if you want to match `.root .abc .child` and `.root .xyz .child`, you can write code like this:

```css
.root :is(.abc, .xyz) .child {
   margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
  <a class="abc">
    <span class="child">Lorem</span>
  </a>
  <a class="xyz">
    <span class="child">Ipsum</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

The difference between **:is** and **:where** is that **:where** is ignored when calculating specificity of the selector:

- specificity of `.root :is(.abc, .xyz) .child` = specificity of `.root .abc .child`
- specificity of `.root :where(.abc, .xyz) .child` = specificity of `.root .child`

Both pseudo-classes accept a *forgiving selector list*, meaning that if one selector fails to be parsed (due to unsupported syntax, either too new, too old or just incorrect), the other selectors would still work. This makes **:is** useful even at the root level, because it allows combining selectors using modern CSS features without fear that one selector will break the rest.

P.S. This question answers a more difficult variation of the question, but Google returns this page on too many queries, so I think this information will be relevant here.

Answer (score 3):

You can apply styles to multiple classes at once, by  just writing their names and separating them with a **comma**.

For example, let's say there are two classes with names "one" and "two" and you have to apply some common styles to both of them. You can have a look at the code given below and understand.

```
.one, .two{ 
display: inline-block;
background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is also a way to use [@extend](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/extend) to achieve this with SCSS.