# JavaFX 2 classes with different name have same css code

Tags: java, css, javafx

It may seem duplicate with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099252/2-classes-with-different-name-should-have-same-property-in-css-without-repeating) question but it is not working.

> Two classes exist which extend `HBox` and have one `TextField` element.I have added on each one a `StyleClass` like this:

```
//for one class
 getStyleClass().add("search-box");

 //for the other class
 getStyleClass().add("libraries-search-box");
```

> So i am modifing the appearence of their `TextField` with the above css code:

```
.search-box .text-field {
    -fx-background-color: white;    
    -fx-background-insets:3.0;
    -fx-background-radius: 5.0;   
     ..... 
}

.libraries-search-box .text-field {
    -fx-background-color: white;    
    -fx-background-insets:3.0;
    -fx-background-radius: 5.0;   
     ....
}
```

> I want to replace the duplicate code and i try:

```
.search-box , .libraries-search-box .text-field {
     -fx-background-color: white;   
    -fx-background-insets:3.0;
    -fx-background-radius: 5.0;
     ...//   
}
```

but it works only for '`.libraries-search-box`'.How i get get it work for both?

Comment: .text-field needs to come after both parents in the selector

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify `.text-field` to both `.search-box` and `.text-field`, as next:

```
.search-box .text-field, .libraries-search-box .text-field {
     -fx-background-color: white;   
    -fx-background-insets:3.0;
    -fx-background-radius: 5.0;
     ...//   
}
```

Indeed `.search-box , .libraries-search-box .text-field` is seen as `.search-box` or `.libraries-search-box .text-field` not as `.search-box .text-field` or `.libraries-search-box .text-field` as you expect.

Comment: Thanks for answer!

Answer (score 1):

The correct format is:

```
.search-box .text-field, .libraries-search-box .text-field {
     -fx-background-color: white;   
    -fx-background-insets:3.0;
    -fx-background-radius: 5.0;
     ...//   
}
```

In your example you defined the CSS attributes for the `.search-box` and the `.libraries-search-box .text-field` class selectors.

Comment: Thanks for answer!