# How to merge several classes in one?

Tags: css, sass

I have several classes provided by the [Quasar framework](https://quasar.dev/). When having several components which are supposed to look the same, I have a repetitive pattern such as

```
<div class="q-ma-xs text-h6 bg-black">one</div>
<div class="q-ma-xs text-h6 bg-black">two</div>
<div class="q-ma-xs text-h6 bg-black">three</div>
(...)
```

I am looking for a way to combine all the classes in one, so that a global modification is applied to all elements.

I was hoping that it is possible to use several [`@extend`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/extend) entries in one new class definition but it does not seem to be the case.

**Is there a CSS/SCSS/SASS way to do such a merge?**

My backup plan is to use `<div :class="myElement">one</div>` where `myElement` is defined in the scripts section (reactivity in Vue) but I would prefer a more native solution.

Comment: Aren't they all have the same class? That mean the style will apply for all?
[If they are different class you can apply style to many classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099252/how-can-i-apply-styles-to-multiple-classes-at-once)

Comment: @Seno: I am not sure I understand your question. Yes, they all have the same classes to have the same style.

Comment: You mention several "components which are supposed to look the same", aren't they gonna be the same if you apply the style?

Comment: @Seno: yes they will, I am not sure what is unclear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have multiple values in `@extend`

```
.myNewClass {
   @extend .q-ma-xs, .text-h6, .bg-black;
}
```

But I would be really careful with that. `@extend` [does some strange stuff](https://webinista.com/updates/dont-use-extend-sass/) with selector hierarchy.

A better solution might be to create mixins for each of the classes and `@include` the mixins.

Comment: Thank you. I read about mixins in the docs (https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/mixin) but I do not see how the multiple inclusion of classes would work. Would that be one mixin that would include a class (one mixin for each class), and then include all the mixins one after each other in the new class? (which is ultimately attached to my element)

Comment: One mixin for each class I think. All depends on what you need to include.

Answer (score 3):

To get @Bryce Howistson answer to work with `@extend`, I had to add

```
@import "node_modules/quasar/src/css/index";
```

In every `.vue` file I wanted to extend quasar classes (in the style tag at the end of the file).

To avoid importing all the components again (heavy index file with all quasar components styling). I went for a custom index file with the following imports:

```
// inside custom file: /src/css/quasar.extend.library.scss
@import "node_modules/quasar/src/css/flex-addon.sass";
@import "node_modules/quasar/src/css/variables.sass";
@import 'node_modules/quasar/src/css/core/animations.sass';
@import 'node_modules/quasar/src/css/core/colors.sass';
@import 'node_modules/quasar/src/css/core/elevation.sass';
@import 'node_modules/quasar/src/css/core/flex.sass';
@import 'node_modules/quasar/src/css/core/helpers.sass';
@import 'node_modules/quasar/src/css/core/mouse.sass';
@import 'node_modules/quasar/src/css/core/orientation.sass';
@import 'node_modules/quasar/src/css/core/positioning.sass';
@import 'node_modules/quasar/src/css/core/size.sass';
@import 'node_modules/quasar/src/css/core/touch.sass';
@import 'node_modules/quasar/src/css/core/transitions.sass';
@import 'node_modules/quasar/src/css/core/typography.sass';
@import 'node_modules/quasar/src/css/core/visibility.sass';
@import 'node_modules/quasar/src/css/core/dark.sass';
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is a nice and simple way to make the workflow smooth!