# How can I apply styles to multiple classes at once in react?

Tags: reactjs, constants

Someone asked this question long time ago for HTML and CSS. Here is the link:
[How can I apply styles to multiple classes at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099252/how-can-i-apply-styles-to-multiple-classes-at-once)

Based on the top answer, we can see that in HTML and CSS this is fixing with comma:

```
.abc, .xyz { 
    margin-left: 20px; 
}
```

How can I do this in react? This is some example which is not working:

```
const StyledTableSortLabel = withStyles((theme) => ({
    root,active,icon,iconDirectionDesc,iconDirectionAsc: {
      color: theme.palette.common.white,
    },
}))(TableSortLabel);
```

Any idea?

Comment: Sorry, you need to be more specific please. The question, as formulated now, does not seem to be exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: I think that is clear what I am trying to achieve, but nevertheless I edited question.